# How to integrate roxy fileman in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, ckeditor, roxy-fileman

I have integrated CKEditor in my codeigniter project. I have integrated CKEditor with Roxy Fileman. I have put the fileman folder in the root folder. But when I click on the "browse server" in CKEditor, it popups a window with URL http://localhost/fileman/index.html?integration=ckeditor&type=image&CKEditor=content&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en and I get an error

Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1j PHP/5.6.3 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3

This happened may be because I don't have a fileman controller. In normal php, I can integrate like this but how to integrate Roxy Fileman with codeigniter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my project was in a sub folder of htdocs I had to change the code from

```js
 var roxyFileman = '/fileman/index.html?integration=ckeditor';
 $(function() {
   CKEDITOR.replace('content', {
     filebrowserBrowseUrl: roxyFileman,
     filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: roxyFileman + '&type=image',
     removeDialogTabs: 'link:upload;image:upload'
   });
 });
```

to

```js
 var roxyFileman = '/projectName/fileman/index.html?integration=ckeditor';
 $(function() {
   CKEDITOR.replace('content', {
     filebrowserBrowseUrl: roxyFileman,
     filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: roxyFileman + '&type=image',
     removeDialogTabs: 'link:upload;image:upload'
   });
 });
```

notice

```js
var roxyFileman = '/projectName/fileman/index.html?integration=ckeditor';
```

has to be changed.